Can't see a window move that I am dragging in a multi-monitor set up
My issue is not that I can't see a window moving from one monitor to the other in an extend screen mode as I am moving it.  I never had this problem until recently.
When I grab the window to drag it either to a different location on the monitor or to the other monitor, I no longer see it being moved.  I have to guess where it should be then let go of dragging and the window appears in the new location.  I much prefer seeing the window move as I drag so I know exactly where I am putting it.

What Windows version? Describe what happened on your computer prior to or around the time the problem first began? Have you checked for and installed any and all updated drivers and firmware, especially the graphics drivers? This is the basic sort of information we'll need to begin helping you, and the sorts of things you should check first with any sort of graphical bug like this. Please complete these tasks and collect this information and then add this information to the question itself. Do not comment the answers down here: Making your question more complete will help get good answers.

Ok will try to update graphics drivers and firmware.  Not sure where to put the answers down since you say not to put the answers in this section?

Graphics drivers are currrent; happened within the last 30 days; can't recall what other things were happening when I first noticed this; sorry to answer here but don't know where else to put what you asked; thanks for your patience and help

I directed you to add these answers to your main question, to the post at the top that you made. You use the EDIT button below your question to add information to it. Please read the HELP section to better understand this site and its rules, standards, and mechanics.
